# Calculae cost SonarQube - Azure

Tags: azure, sonarqube

I need to know how much will cost to deploy SonarQube on Azure. I will deploy the following:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/sonarqube-azuresql/

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sonarqube-azuresql/

How can I calculate the cost to deploy this? Exist there an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the resources listed in the ARM template, and enter them in the [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). Anything more requires more detail in your question, and is probably outside the scope of Stackoverflow.